# How do I specify using a view with a compiled handlebar in ember.js RC1

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to port a pre2 application to 1.0.0 rc. They way my application is setup is as follow:  all my templates are compiled into their own view.

So my code looked like this:

```
    App.NewUserController = Em.Controller.extend({});
    App.NewUserView = Em.View.extend({
        template: Em.Handlebars.compile(NewUserHtml)
    });
```

NewUserHtml is a html/handlebars file loaded through require.js.

Since the file is directly compiled into the template it doesn't include a `<script type="text/x-handlebars"…>`tag.

I understand that I need to override the render function of my route, but the options I have seen seem to require that I specify a template and I don't really have one. In my case since the template is already in my view, I am looking for a way to just specify the view to use.

I am probably doing something fundamentally anti-rc 1.0...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: See my Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676017/ember-js-rc1-view-not-displayed-when-specifying-template --- it seems as though the `template` function is rather finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that NewUserHtml is just plain text with handlebars tags, you should be able to do something like this in your view:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['NewUser'] = Handlebars.compile(NewUserHtml);
App.NewUserView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'NewUser'
});
```

or

```
App.NewUserView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile(NewUserHtml)
});
```

or

```
App.NewUserView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'some-other-template'
});
```

You can read more about views [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html), 'templates' section.

Comment: I have been unable to get the second scenario to work. Even if I specify the compiled template, I still have to add a reference to the template in `Ember.TEMPLATES`. :[

Comment: i have made some progress by removing the views whose only purpose is to hold the template and adding the compiled template to Em.TEMPLATES… I am not sure whether it is standard since I don't see that documented anywhere (or did I miss something?) I haven't dealt with more complicated views. But I'll accept this answer. And ask about other issues as I forge ahead.