# Ember.js RC1 - view not displayed when specifying 'template'

Tags: ember.js

Following the Ember guide on templates I do the following:

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('I am the template')
});
```

But nothing is rendered.  When I use the `templateName` the view *is* rendered:

// html

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='posts-template'>
    <h1>I am the template</h1>
</script>
```

// js

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'posts-template'
});
```

How can I get the templates to work using the `template` function as stated in the guides?

**edit:**

I did come across these:

[emberjs template compile doesn't work in rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984207/emberjs-template-compile-doesnt-work-in-rc1)

[How do I specify using a view with a compiled handlebar in ember.js RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915027/how-do-i-specify-using-a-view-with-a-compiled-handlebar-in-ember-js-rc1)

So this *might* look like a duplicate.  However, this first appears to use some extra work not specified in the Ember guides and the second is what I am doing but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this works:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['posts-template'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('I am the template');
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'posts-template'
});
```

What was happening in our was that our **pre-compiled** templates were being added to `Handlebars.templates` and not `Ember.TEMPLATES` along with the fact that we were returning the complied template using this, e.g.:

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.templates['posts-template']
});
```

So it seems as though one should refrain from interfering with the `template` function but rather *always* use the `templateName` which will be looking for that name in `Ember.TEMPLATES`.

Hopefully this helps someone save some time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the expected `templateName` along with the actual `template` contents:

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'posts',
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('I am the template')
});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/271/edit)

Comment: That is rather strange.  According to this page: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html --- "Assigning a value to both template and templateName properties will throw an error."

Comment: This describes the issue you're seeing: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2030